# Can we modify limits.h? Would it render any effect?

Tags: c, linux, header, kernel, posix

Let's say we want to change the value of maximum number of precesses each uid can execute contemporarily, what if we modify value CHILD_MAX in limits.h.
Is the value in limits.h just set in order to let us know the 'limits', or we can actually manipulate our system with it?
I think since kernel is not recompiled, there should be no reason that we can change the system behaviour in such way.

Comment: Right, the kernel doesn't care about what you do to your `limits.h`. (But there's no `CHILD_MAX` in my `limits.h`, since that is an OS limit, and not a C limit.)

Comment: Confusingly, you can redefine FD_SETSIZE and get support for more fds (not that that's in limits.h, but you might have seen that somewhere).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values in `<limits.h>` are just there to inform you of the actual limits.  Redefining the macros will not change the actual limits.